# A formula involving generalized inverse of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

(1) $  A \,\ is \,\  n \times m$ therefore $  A' \,\ is \,\  m \times n$

(2) $ A^+ $ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$

(3) $ B $ is an $n \times n$ and invertible symmetric matrix. We could add positive definiteness if it helps.

(4) $(A'B^{-1} A)^{-1}$ exists.

Under what conditions $(A'B^{-1} A)^{-1}= A'^{+} B A^+ $ is true?

Comment: Without any loss of generality you can take $B$ to be the identity (choose a suitable basis).  Can you go on from there?  In particular, this shows the left hand side of your equation doesn't necessarily exist, so are you sure you have formulated the question as you intended?

Comment: @whuber The existence of the left hand side is among the assumptions of the question.

Comment: Without a statistical component, this a pure linear algebra question, which belongs elsewhere.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I would suppose so, but according to the information given, (4) is nonsense because it would multiply an $n\times n$ matrix $B^{-1}$ on its *right* by an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ ;-). Although that problem is easily rectified, the larger point is that *any question posed entirely mathematically, with no statistical context, must be framed **absolutely correctly** to be understood,* because there is little basis to make educated guesses about the intended question otherwise.